# Объединение ячеек, заливка цветом, добавление примечания

Tags: google-apps-script

Как в Таблицах Гугл нарисовать кнопки, при нажатии на которые объединялись бы и заливались выделенные пользователем ячейки определенным цветом? То есть пользователь выделяет диапазон ячеек, нажимает на кнопку:

[image: кнопка]

После чего диапазон ячеек становится одной ячейкой, заливается заданным цветом и в эту ячейку добавляется заранее заготовленный шаблон примечания:

[image: Готовые ячейки]

Желательно чтобы фон заливки у примечания тоже изменялся. Был, например, приятно желтоватым.

И нужна еще кнопка очистки. То есть пользователь выделяет ячейку, которая окрашена в цвет, там есть запись и примечание, нажимает на кнопку очистки и эта объединенная ячейка заливается белым цветом по умолчанию, оттуда удаляются все данные, и она снова становится множеством ячеек, каким была до объединения. С Google Apps Script ранее не сталкивался.

Comment: _С Google Apps Script ранее не сталкивался_ - ну так столкнитесь. Как возникнут трудности - милости просим на StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужен программист, а не код. "Кнопочки" на поле Таблицы - не самый лучший вариант. Все же меню является более удачным вариантом.

### Меню

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Объединятор')
    .addItem('Объединить', 'mergeAction')
    .addItem('Разъединить', 'unmergeAction')
    .addToUi();
}
```

### Объединение

```
function mergeAction() {
  var ar = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  ar.merge().setBackground('orange').setNote('abc');
};
```

### Разъединение

```
function unmergeAction() {
  var ar = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  ar.breakApart().clear().clearNote();
}
```

Важно отметить, что с некоторых пор `breakApart` работает без ошибок и лишних исключений, что не может не радовать.

Comment: Еще забыл уточнить, что изначально рабочая область - это таблица. И когда срабатывает clear(), то очищаются и границы ячеек. Как сделать так, чтобы очищались заливка, содержимое, но в то же время выделенная область оставалась бы частью таблицы в таком виде, каком была до объединения?

Comment: @ДмитрийТихонов, попробуйте _[clear(options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearoptions)_.

Comment: пробовал. По крайней в официальной документации не нашлось такого параметра clear(), который бы решал поставленную задачу